# Mounted with bind folder doesn't appear in FTP client if mounted a folder in a volume

Tags: ftp, centos6, mount

I mounted an external folder (from outside the ftp folder) in the ftp folder with mount bind parameter this way:

```
mount --bind sourcefolder destinationfolder
```

The folder is correctly mounted and I can see the files in my ssh client but if I connect to the FTP, the mounted folder simply doesn't appear. If I try to create a folder with the same name in the ftp client obviosly it doesn't allow me to create it because the same folder already exists.
My vsftpd configuration looks as following:
(The vsftpd is running under openVPN, don't know if this could be the problem)

Please note: I tryed to mount with bind a folder located in an external volume (partition).
If I mount a folder in the same partition as the FTP folder, it works.
But I need to mount the other partition volume.

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
listen=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
userlist_deny=NO
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd/users_allow
listen_address=10.8.0.1
pasv_enable=YES
```

The used client is Filezilla 3.7.0.2

Comment: Have you tried restarting the ftp daemon?  It may open the directory when the daemon starts, and then just keep it open.

Comment: I tryed to restart without success

Comment: I edited my question. Basically the problem seems to appear only when I mount with bind an external volume (folder in different partition), already mounted.

Comment: @ClaudioFerraro did you find a solution ? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you mount the folder with the `allow_other` option, the disk will show up:

```
mount --bind ​-o allow_other sourcefolder destinationfolder
```

This is because the `vsftpd` process needs to be able to access the mounted directory as well in order to show it to the client.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).