# contents of mounted drive not visible in Apache/2.4.18 (ubuntu)

Tags: apache-2.4, mount

This question was initially posted on Super User. I didn't get any answer there so re-posting here:

Our cluster's apache setup is as such: each user has a directory `~/public_html`, and any files (including soft linked files) inside this directory are accessible through http. I have files on another server (serverB) which I mounted to our cluster using the flowing command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o vers=3.0,uid=10069,gid=10069,credentials=secrets //xxx.xxx.edu/path/to/source public_html/serverB
```

When I ssh into the cluster, I could assess all mounted files just as if they were present on the cluster. I could also see a folder named "serverB" on http. However, serverB appears as an empty folder on http, with none of its contents visible. I was wondering if it's at all possible to make all contents of mounted serverB available through http as well?

I did further research on related topics. This post is describing a very similar issue (unsolved, unfortunately):
[Cannot see mounted CIFS directory from FTP client](https://serverfault.com/questions/826363/cannot-see-mounted-cifs-directory-from-ftp-client)

A few other posts mentioned a "allow_other" option, but it seems to be specific to `mount --bind` or `s3fs`, unless I'm missing something.

- [Mounted with bind folder doesn't appear in FTP client if mounted a folder in a volume](https://serverfault.com/questions/686879/mounted-with-bind-folder-doesnt-appear-in-ftp-client-if-mounted-a-folder-in-a-v)
- https://superuser.com/questions/1391659/mounted-volume-does-not-appear-in-ftp-client-using-vsftpd

Answer (score 0):

Try to mount your share using the dir_mode and file_mode to something like 0550 (files and folder accessible in read and execute).

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o vers=3.0,uid=10069,gid=10069,dir_mode=0550,file_mode=0550,credentials=secrets //xxx.xxx.edu/path/to/source public_html/serverB
```

Best regards.

Comment: contents of the mounted directory still not visible with 0550 or 0777. Thanks for the answer though.